# extract function conversion from oracle to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change this oracle query to postgressql query but its not working for me:

Oracle Query:

```
select XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, line_prefix || ',')).EXTRACT (' //text()'), ',') from in_line
```

Postgresql Query:

```
 SELECT XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ( name a_line,line_prefix||','))
 FROM in_line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a workaround using XMLAGG in Postgres to create a comma separated string. This can be done using `string_agg()`

```
SELECT string_agg(line_prefix, ',')
FROM in_line
```